# (bitbucket-pipelines.)yml file has weird indentation?

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Why is every section in this file indented by 2 except the step

```
  image: atlassian/default-image:2
  pipelines:
    default:
    - step:
        deployment: production
        script:
        - git submodule update --recursive --init
        - zip -r $FILENAME . -x bitbucket-pipelines.yml *.git*
        - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.1.6
          variables:
            BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
            BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
            FILENAME: $FILENAME
```

And gives an error if changed to two?

https://bitbucket-pipelines.prod.public.atl-paas.net/validator

This topic seems to say because YAML does not consider `-` to be the first character? But after pipe is the same sequence with only two?

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Is-it-intentional-that-bitbucket-pipelinese-yml-indentation/qaq-p/582084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will usually see two things in YAML

1. Sequences — in other programming languages, this is commonly referred as arrays, lists, ...:

   ```yaml
   - apple
   - banana
   - pear
   ```
2. Mappings — in other programming languages, this is commonly referred as objects, hashes, dictionaries, associative arrays, ...:

   ```yaml
   question: how do I foobar?
   body: Can you help?
   tag: yaml
   ```

So if you want to store a mapping of mapping you would do:

```yaml
pier1:
  boat: yes
  in_activity: yes
  comments: needs some painting in 2023
## The mapping above this comment refers to the pier1, 
## as it is indented one level below the key `pier1`

pier2:
  boat: no
  in_activity: no
  comments: currently inactive, needs urgent repair
## The mapping above this comment refers to the pier2,
## as it is indented one level below the key `pier2`
```

While, if you store a list in a mapping, you could go without the indent, indeed:

```yaml
fruits:
- apple
- banana
- pear
```

Is strictly equal to

```yaml
fruits:
  - apple
  - banana
  - pear
```

---

But, if you are trying to indent the first step of your pipeline only, like so:

```yaml
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      deployment: production
```

You end up with an valid YAML, but, **a YAML that does not have the same meaning anymore**.

When your original yaml means: *I do have a default pipeline with a list of actions, the first action being a step that consists of a deployment to production*.
The resulting incorrectly indented YAML means: *I do have a default pipeline with a list of actions, **the first action having two properties, the first property being an empty step, and the second property is that it is a deployment to production***.

So, here, really, the `deplyement` key that was a property of the step mapping became a property of the first element of the list `default`!

To indent all this as you would like, you will have to go:

```yaml
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        deployment: production
##      ^-- This property is now further indented too
```

So, you end up with the YAML:

```yaml
image: atlassian/default-image:2
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        deployment: production
        script:
          - git submodule update --recursive --init
          - zip -r $FILENAME . -x bitbucket-pipelines.yml *.git*
          - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.1.6
            variables:
              BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
              BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
              FILENAME: $FILENAME
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC the issue is that

```
- step:
```

is *really* two lines but combined into one for convenience, so - which identifies a sequence item (and hence implicitly a sequence to contain it) then step: which defines a mapping key and hence implicitly a mapping to contain it.

You could break it into two lines and the indentation would be more intuitive:

```
-
  step:
    deployment: production
```

I found this tool useful for seeing how it was being interpreted: https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json. e.g. above comes out as

```
[
  {
    "step": {
      "deployment": "production"
    }
  }
]
```

whereas

```
- step:
  deployment: production
```

comes out as

```
[
  {
    "step": null,
    "deployment": "production"
  }
]
```

as previous poster suggested.